# Объясните пожалуйста, как выровнить текст внутри дочернего элемента (используется css grid)

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, frontend, css-grid

Только начинаю изучать CSS grid и не могу разобраться с выравниванием текста по вертикали (хочу понять как расположить цифры по центру дочерних элементов). Объясните пожалуйста, как это сделать.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 5px;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 300px 300px;
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 100px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item_1">1</div>
  <div class="item_2">2</div>
  <div class="item_3">3</div>
  <div class="item_4">4</div>
  <div class="item_5">5</div>
  <div class="item_6">6</div>
</div>
```

Ссылка на код: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XYRBob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.wrapper > div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

На внутренности гридов распространяются свойства Box alignment, вам надо просто добавить элементу обертке `align-items: center`.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 5px;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 300px 300px;
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 100px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item_1">1</div>
  <div class="item_2">2</div>
  <div class="item_3">3</div>
  <div class="item_4">4</div>
  <div class="item_5">5</div>
  <div class="item_6">6</div>
</div>
```